# Map every 2 elements to a function/constructor

Tags: f#

I have an integer array in which I want to send every two elements from it to the constructor of another function.

Something like `intArray |> Array.map (fun x, y -> new Point(x, y))`

Is this possible? I'm new to F# and functional programming so I'm trying to avoid just looping through every 2 items in the array and adding the point to a list. I hope that's reasonable.

Comment: Would `[1;2;3;4]` result in just two points (1,2) and (3,4), or would it be 3 points (1,2) (2,3) and (3,4)?

Comment: [1;2;3;4] would be (1,2) and (3,4).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using F# 4.0, use Gustavo's approach.  For F# 3, you can do:

```
intArray
    |> Seq.pairwise // get sequence of tuples of element (1,2); (2,3); (3,4); (4,5) etc
    |> Seq.mapi (fun i xy -> i, xy) // combine the index with the tuple
    |> Seq.filter (fun (i,_) -> i % 2 = 0) // Filter for only the even indices to get (1,2); (3,4)
    |> Seq.map (fun xy -> Point xy) // make a point from the tuples
    |> Array.ofSeq // convert back to array
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Array.chunkBySize`:

```
intArray 
    |> Array.chunkBySize 2 
    |> Array.map (function 
        | [|x; y|] -> new Point (x, y) 
        | _ -> failwith "Array length is not even.")
```

Comment: I don't know of any Array.chunkBySize function, it certainly doesn't appear in the MSDN documentation for the Collections.Array module.

Comment: No, because it's from F# 4.0 . They didn't update MSDN ;)

Comment: Ah, that explains it - that's what I get for writing code on my laptop where I don't have the F# 4.0 compiler.  I'll update my answer to reflect the F# version.

Comment: @TheInnerLight I see in your answer you are converting to seq to avoid copying the whole array in each operation. It worths mention here you can do the same if that's the goal. Or use a fold, you know, it really depends what are you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to the existing answers, would be to write a custom function, that creates a list/an array of tuples using pattern matching:

```
let chunkify arr =
    let rec chunkify acc lst =
        if (List.length lst) > 1 then (* proceed if there are at least two elements *)
            match lst with 
            (* save every constructed pair, until the input is not empty *)
            | h1 :: h2 :: tail -> chunkify ([(h1, h2)] @ acc) tail
            | _ -> acc (* else return the list of pairs *)
        else (* return the list of pairs *)
            acc

    chunkify List.empty (List.ofSeq arr) |> List.rev |> Array.ofSeq
```

The function can be then used like this:

```
// helper
let print = (fun (x:'a, y:'a) -> printfn "new Object(%A,%A)" x y)
// ints
[|1;2;3;4;5;6|] 
|> chunkify 
|> Array.iter print
// strings
[|"a";"b";"c";"d";"e"|] 
|> chunkify 
|> Array.map print 
|> ignore
```

The output is:

```
new Object(1,2)
new Object(3,4)
new Object(5,6)
new Object("a","b")
new Object("c","d")
```

This solution/approach uses [pattern matching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx) with [lists](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2008/07/10/mastering-f-lists.aspx).